# Is Sending a POST request from POSTman different from sending a POST request from Android (Java)?

Tags: javascript, android, express

I am trying to send a simple POST request from Android to my Node.js application. I am using Volley to send the request. Here is the code from Android Side.

```
 StringRequest stringRequest=new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, constants.link,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),error.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    })
    {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String,String> params=new HashMap<>();
            params.put("number","my-phone-number");
            params.put("text","Hello World");
            return params;
        }
    };
    RequestQueue requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(menu.this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```

Now, when I use this code to send a POST request to a PHP web API, it works fine. But when I use this code to access the endpoints of my NODE.js application. It does send request but it isn't sending the parameters with it.

Here is code of my Node.js Application:

````
var app=express();
var bodyParser=require('body-parser');
const port = 3001
var telnyx = require('telnyx')(MY_API_KEY);
var count=0;
var access=0;


app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get("/app",function(req,res,next){
    //console.log(req);
    console.log(req.query.number);
    console.log(req.query.text);
    res.send("I am get method"+access);
    access++;

});

app.post("/app",function(req,res,next){
  //  console.log(req);
  
   sendSMS(req.query.number,req.query.text);
    res.send("I am post method "+ access + " " + req.query.number + " " + req.query.text);
    access++;
});


app.listen(port,function(){
console.log("Started on port "+port);

});



function sendSMS(num,text) {
console.log("inside function"+num+"  "+text);
    telnyx.messages.create(
      {
        'from': '+15074077011', // Your Telnyx number
        'to': '+'+ num,
        'text': text
      },
      function (err, response) {
        // asynchronously called
        // console.log(response);
        console.log("message sent  "+text+" "+num);
        count++
  
      }
    );
  }```

   
Now when I send a POST request from POSTMAN to this NODE.js application it works fine and I get a message on my Mobile Phone. But when I try to send a post request from android(code is given above), the request sends and the response comes but the parameters stay empty.

1). Is the POST request coming from POSTMAN different from that of Volley from Android
2). How can I send a POST request from Android with parameters that I can catch in my NODE.js application properly?
````

Answer (score 0):

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

requires params sent in the BODY field of Request and not as URL-param.

You're sending the request something like "*../app?number=123&text=message*", instead you have to do:

```
JSONObject bodyParams = new JSONObject();
bodyParams.put("number", "1234");
bodyParams.put("text", "message");
JsonObjectRequest jsonRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, paramJson,
    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

        }
    },
    new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });
requestQueue.add(jsonRequest);
```